# Next js custom document ->move inline script

Tags: reactjs, optimization, next.js

I am new to next.js. I have been trying to optimize my app's performance. I need to move dynamic js files created by Next.js from head to body tag.
[image]

I tried removing NextScript from _document.js, but it didn't work

Comment: Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend moving those. What performance metric are you trying to optimise? Have you looked into other things that can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer

These are default NextJS components that should load first in order to initialize the application and improve customers ability to interact with the *hydrated* components, without this you might impact nextjs Hydration however may potentially improve content scores that the browser pre-parser may render.

### A Custom NextJS Head

In order to achieve this, check this article out to do a custom head element with a document, this is one level up than just removing the NextJS scripts

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

While this [article](https://www.tezify.com/how-to/avoid-preloading-scripts-with-nextjs/) discusses removing the preload scripts, you would need to override the default `head` behavior to skip the script printing but have to re-do it in the body.